# Speedtouch 121g not recognized

Tags: wireless

I sometimes use my speedtouch 121g dongle on my ubuntu pc by installing the `ndiswrapper` and `linux-firmware-nonfree` packages.
EDIT: scratch the previous edit, I only found out that you don't need ndiswrapper.

However when i install `ndiswrapper` and `firmware-linux-nonfree` (yes, the name is different), my raspberry pi won't recognize it. Any help?

Comment: Yay, i got tumbleweed -_- I am sooo happy now...

Comment: Can you give some more information, e.g. the output of `lsusb` for that particular device? Then we can try to determine which chip is in your dongle. Ndiswrapper sounds like a bad idea, since it is a wrapper for x86 Windows drivers, and you are on a ARM platform.

Comment: On my pc I get: Bus 001 Device 003: ID 06b9:0121 Alcatel Telecom SpeedTouch 121g Wireless Dongle. On the RPi it doesn't detect it using lsusb

Comment: That last one is a bad sign. How is the dongle connected -- hub or directly? What power supply are you  using?

Comment: I think directly (connecting the usb to the pi through the standard usb ports) and the power is (temporarily) delivered by the usb port on the back of my router.

Comment: The router might not be able to supply enough power. You should look out for a 5V 1A USB power supply, or better.

Comment: I have exactly that amount of power on an ac>usb adapter. Still no lsusb output :/ EDIT: When I reconnected the dongle it detected it: "Bus 001 Device 087: ID 06b9:0121 Alcatel Telecom SpeedTouch 121g Wireless Dongle", but neither iwconfig nor ifconfig detects it :/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8283/discussion-between-arne-and-mid-kid)

Comment: Well i have exactly the same dongle, and it get recognized in lsusb. Sorry to dig that out but did you manage to get it work in the end ? Solution/hints would be very appreciated. (cc @Arne)

Comment: @y_nk I gave it up. Bought a different dongle.

Comment: @mid_kid if interested i found answers here : http://blog.philippklaus.de/2013/06/wifi-adapter-siemens-gigaset-usb-adapter-54-on-arch-linux-arm-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your device seems to employ a Prism54 chip, according to the [Raspberry Pi Wiki](http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#Working_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters). Furthermore the Wiki says that you need a powered Hub for this device, probably because it consumes quite a bit of power.

If you still want to stick with the device, the Wiki recommends to follow the instructions [in the Debian Wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/prism54). But maybe the firmware is already included in the non-free firmware package, so you might get lucky by just using the powered hub.

Instead of buying a powered hub, you could also buy one of the many dongles utilizing a Realtek chip, as for example the TP-Link TL-WN725N. That one doesn't need a powered hub either, and it is rather cheap and very small.